# How to SELECT value from one table based on same value's behavior in another table?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

Please help me with this... If I have these tables and columns: `TABLE1` with column `ID` and `TABLE2` which has the columns `FOO` and `BAR`, both of which contain different id's which all also appear in the `ID` column of `TABLE1`.

I'd like to write a `SELECT` query to get all id's from `ID` from `TABLE1` but under this condition:

For example, id `101` will be selected from `ID` if the number (`X`) of rows where id `101` appears under the `FOO` column of `TABLE2` when divided by the number (`Y`) of rows where id `101` appears under the `BAR` column of `TABLE2`, gives a result smaller than a certain value.

So if, say, `X / Y < 3`, then id `101` will be selected by the query.

How would such a query look and could it be done in one long query?

Thank you!

Comment: Written out as prose, this is a confusing read. Can you please post a sample of rows from each table, along with a sample of what your query's expected output would be?

Comment: `X = COUNT(FOO)` while `Y = COUNT(BAR)`, grouped by `ID`, is that correct?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski I think you got it wrong. X is the number of times that a certain value from column FOO repeats on table2, and Y is the number of times that a value repeats from column BAR.

Comment: @Lamak That's what I meant to say, but rather than "grouped by ID" more correct is `X = COUNT(FOO) WHERE FOO = 101` and `Y = COUNT(BAR) WHERE BAR = 101` (why I asked for an example anyway `:)` )

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a JOIN with [subqueries in the FROM clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/from-clause-subqueries.html).
The subquery `q1` counts the IDs in the foo column that are in both the foo and id columns.

`SELECT foo as id
FROM
(SELECT foo, COUNT(foo) X FROM Table2 WHERE FOO in
    (SELECT id FROM Table1) GROUP BY foo) q1, 
(SELECT bar, COUNT(bar) Y FROM Table2 WHERE bar in
    (SELECT id FROM Table1) GROUP BY bar) q2
WHERE q1.foo=q2.bar and X/Y < 3`

Comment: I know the question is not very clear and well asked... but this answer (which I got in my review queue) is also low quality. Please refine it and add some explanation, or reference or whatever it takes to make it a better answer ;)

Comment: It would improve the answer for future readers if you gave a bit of explanation about the query.